# How to use the same data with all mappers?

Tags: java, hadoop, machine-learning, random-forest

As we know, the number of mapper is defined by the data splits, then the problem comes, if I want to implement a random forest algorithm with MapReduce, where each mapper requires all the data. What should I do within that case? Could we "reuse" the data for different mappers?

Could `setNumMapTasks` works? I am quite confused about that function, and I could hardly find any information regarding how it works against the natural number of mappers decided by the number of data splits.

Thank you so much.

Comment: If you build a random forest, why does each mapper need all the data? You would first bag the data into different files and then let each mapper build a decision tree for the forest.

Answer (score 0):

`Side data` is data shared by all mappers. You will want to broadcast the data to the mappers as part of the Job setup.

This is accomplished via the `DistributedCache` https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html  .

Here ar some code starting points.  First place the files you want to share within the DistributedCache via the `Job` class:

```
        job.addCacheFile(new URI("<your file location>"));
```

In the mapper/ reducer you access the file via normal FileSystem api:

```
File file = new File("<my file name>");
```